# Reading Docker container status inside application

Tags: c++, docker, containers

I have a C++ application containerised as docker container. I have come across a scenario where the docker daemon on a host where the docker containers are running ,goes down. Thereby the container run time also goes down. How do i read this status inside the application which is residing in the container itself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the application is in the container, and the container is exited, then the application is exited, and there's not really anything you can check.  Or am I misunderstanding the setup?

Answer (score 0):

Use --network="host" in your docker run command, then 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host. You can then ping 127.0.0.1 from your container to get the status of your host. But I don't see a point of doing it because if your host is going down, anyways containers would be the first to loose network connectivity and you won't be able to read the status inside the application ever.

Recommended way is to perform container orchestration using swarm, k8s, openshift etc to avoid this issue.